# How can I record audio output from command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, audio-recording

I want to record the output of audio to an mp3 file. What tools and commands can I use in the Ubuntu Linux terminal?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/229352/how-to-record-output-to-speakers

Comment: Try `arecord -vv -fdat stackoverflow.wav` and then convert into mp3 with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Note that `arecord` records using 8kHz by default(!). Use --rate 44100 (or minimally 16000)  to increase the sampling frequency.

Answer (score 14):

Other answers suggested the following tools: `sox`, `arecord`, and `parec`. Additionally, [PipeWire](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire) users may use `pw-cat`, although the other tools work with PipeWire also. They can all be invoked simply:

### [`arecord`](https://manpages.org/arecord)

```
arecord --format=cd file.wav
```

It saves in `.wav` by default. If you don't specify a decent format, the default audio quality is poor. One feature I like about this program is its nice vumeter graphical output. It also supports dynamic output filenaming (via hour, minute, day...). Unfortunately, it can't output to ogg or mp3.

---

### [`sox`](https://manpages.org/sox)

```
rec file.ext
```

This program doesn't currently work with zsh completions. It displays a meter in its graphical output, but it displays other information also. It supports mp3 and ogg.

---

### [`pacat`](https://manpages.org/pacat)

```
parecord file.ext
```

It supports mp3 and ogg. But it can't display a meter in its graphical output.

---

### [`pw-cat`](https://docs.pipewire.org/page_man_pw_cat_1.html)

```
pw-record file.ext
```

It's `pacat` for PipeWire. It supports custom quality settings for ogg and mp3, whereas `pacat` doesn't. It doesn't have a metered graphical output either.

To record from a different audio device, a headset for example, you can use one of the methods listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22031/what-are-my-audio-devices/22036#1412506) to first get the name of your recording device. For example:

```
pw-cli list-objects | grep node.name
```

Assuming this has yielded "alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Wireless_Headset.mono", we then use that name with the `--target` option:

```
pw-record --target alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Wireless_Headset.mono file.wav
```

Answer (score 5):

First you need to extract the name of your output device:

To do this, you can install the following packets:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-utils lame mpg123
```

And run:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index' -e 'Speakers'
```

The output could be like this:

```
index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
index: 23
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-surround71>
```

After you found the name, you can run the following command to record the output to an mp3 file:

```
parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor | lame -r -V0 - out.mp3
```

Or using `sox` you can do the following, however I found the first solution more robust:

```
sox -t pulseaudio alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor -t mp3 test.mp3
```

However, if you want to automatically start and stop recording you can run:

```
parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor | sox -t raw -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -r 44100 - test.ogg silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%
```

It begins recording when a sound is sent to the speaker and stops if nothing is received after 3 seconds. For more information about `sox`, refer to its [man page for Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox).

Comment: Great info! As an aside, pacmd list-sinks no longer works on newer systems that use pipewire-pulseaudio backend.
But this does. `pactl list|grep monitor`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`arecord`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arecord) for this.

Get your available devices with `arecord -l`. This will produce something like this:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20590 Analog [CX20590 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Then, to record using the USB microphone (card 1, subdevice 0) use, for example:

```
arecord --device="hw:1,0" --format=s16_le --rate=48 rec_$(date "+%F_%H-%M-%S").wav
```

There's also `-f cd` which is a shortcut for `--format=s16_le --rate=44100`.

### Set default audio source

When you don't provide `--device`, `arecord` will record from the *default* audio source. To show the current default source, run

```
pactl info | grep "Default Source"
```

To change the default source using a minimal textual menu, you can use [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf):

```
pactl set-default-source $(pactl list short sources | cut -f2 | fzf)
```

I find this more comfortable than looking up the card and subdevice indices.

### Listen while recording

It's often useful to listen to an audio device and record from it at the same time. We can do this by making `arecord` write to standard out with `-` and then pipe that audio data to [`tee`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) which writes the audio to a file and passes it along to `aplay`:

```
arecord -f cd - | tee rec.wav | aplay -
```

### File conversion

Convert the WAVE file to a format of your choice:

- To [MP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3): `ffmpeg -i rec.wav rec.mp3`
- To [Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg): `ffmpeg -i rec.wav rec.ogg`
- To [FLAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC): `flac rec.wav -o rec.flac`

Answer (score 2):

Kudos to @Ahmad. This worked for me:

```
sox -e signed-integer -L -b16 -c2 -r44100 -t raw "|parec -d alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.4.iec958-stereo.monitor" -t mp3 -c2 -C 320.01 stream.mp3 silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%
```

where input stream parameters can be seen with `pacmd list-sinks`:

```
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.4.iec958-stereo>
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
```